# Solving an equation, and verifying that it is correct

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I want to solve the equation

```
 Solve[e == 1/2 (-2 ef + hvk - Sqrt[9 hvk^2 + 4 j^2]), hvk]
```

I then obtain the solutions

```
{{hvk ->
    1/4 (-e - ef - Sqrt[9 e^2 + 18 e ef + 9 ef^2 - 8 j^2])}, {hvk -> 
   1/4 (-e - ef + Sqrt[9 e^2 + 18 e ef + 9 ef^2 - 8 j^2])}}
```

To verify that they are solutions I expect that the command

```
FullSimplify[
 Refine[1/2 (-2 ef + hvk - Sqrt[9 hvk^2 + 4 j^2]) /. 
   hvk -> 1/4 (-e - ef + Sqrt[9 e^2 + 18 e ef + 9 ef^2 - 8 j^2])]]
```

Should produce the variable $e$. However, I instead obtain

```
1/8 (-e - 9 ef + Sqrt[9 (e + ef)^2 - 8 j^2] - 
   4 Sqrt[4 j^2 + 9/16 (e + ef - Sqrt[9 (e + ef)^2 - 8 j^2])^2])
```

which I can not simplify to $e$. What on earth is going on?

I have used the following assumptions in Refine

```
$Assumptions = {j >=  0, e > 0,
  Element[ef, Reals]}
```

Comment: Did you try `Reduce[e == 1/2 (-2 ef + hvk - Sqrt[9 hvk^2 + 4 j^2]), hvk, Reals]`?

Comment: Depending on the values of the parameters, one or both might be parasite solutions (they solve a "polynomialized" version wherein radicals are removed, but turn out to be conjugates rather than actual solutions).  Check this with e.g. `vars = {e, ef, j};
residuals = 
 Table[-e + 1/2 (-2 ef + hvk - Sqrt[9 hvk^2 + 4 j^2]) /. soln /. 
    Thread[vars -> RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, 3]], {100}] // Chop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you obtained is clearly not the right solution:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
$Assumptions = {};
EQ = e == 1/2 (-2 ef + hvk - Sqrt[9 hvk^2 + 4 j^2]);
sol = Solve[EQ, hvk]
hvksol[ef_, e_, j_] = hvk //. sol[[1]];

N[EQ[[2]] //. {e -> 3, ef -> 4, j -> 2, hvk -> hvksol[4, 3, 2]}]
```

And the ouput:

```
-17.8059
```

Note that if you use `$Assumptions$` you define a default value for `Assumptions`. As you might read [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html). Ig you apply those assumptions, you get totally different results:

```
$Assumptions = {j >= 0, e > 0, Element[ef, Reals]};
EQ = e == 1/2 (-2 ef + hvk - Sqrt[9 hvk^2 + 4 j^2]);
sol = Solve[EQ, hvk]
```

Output:

```
{{hvk -> ConditionalExpression[
    1/4 (-e - ef) - (
     I Sqrt[-e^2 + 1/4 e (-e - ef) + 1/8 (-e - ef)^2 - 2 e ef + 
       1/4 (-e - ef) ef - ef^2 + j^2])/Sqrt[2], 
    e + ef < 0 && 
     ef < 0 && -4 j + 3 Sqrt[2] Abs[e + ef] < 0]}, {hvk -> 
   ConditionalExpression[
    1/4 (-e - ef) + (
     I Sqrt[-e^2 + 1/4 e (-e - ef) + 1/8 (-e - ef)^2 - 2 e ef + 
       1/4 (-e - ef) ef - ef^2 + j^2])/Sqrt[2], 
    e + ef < 0 && 
     ef < 0 && -4 j + 3 Sqrt[2] Abs[e + ef] < 0]}, {hvk -> 
   ConditionalExpression[
    1/4 (-e - ef) - 1/4 Sqrt[9 e^2 + 18 e ef + 9 ef^2 - 8 j^2] - (
     I Sqrt[-e^2 - 2 e ef - ef^2 + j^2 + 
       e (1/4 (-e - ef) - 
          1/4 Sqrt[9 e^2 + 18 e ef + 9 ef^2 - 8 j^2]) + 
       ef (1/4 (-e - ef) - 
          1/4 Sqrt[9 e^2 + 18 e ef + 9 ef^2 - 8 j^2]) + 
       2 (1/4 (-e - ef) - 
          1/4 Sqrt[9 e^2 + 18 e ef + 9 ef^2 - 8 j^2])^2])/Sqrt[2], 
    e + ef < 0 && -4 j + 3 Sqrt[2] Abs[e + ef] > 0 && 
     ef < 0]}, {hvk -> 
   ConditionalExpression[
    1/4 (-e - ef) + 1/4 Sqrt[9 e^2 + 18 e ef + 9 ef^2 - 8 j^2] - (
     I Sqrt[-e^2 - 2 e ef - ef^2 + j^2 + 
       e (1/4 (-e - ef) + 
          1/4 Sqrt[9 e^2 + 18 e ef + 9 ef^2 - 8 j^2]) + 
       ef (1/4 (-e - ef) + 
          1/4 Sqrt[9 e^2 + 18 e ef + 9 ef^2 - 8 j^2]) + 
       2 (1/4 (-e - ef) + 
          1/4 Sqrt[9 e^2 + 18 e ef + 9 ef^2 - 8 j^2])^2])/Sqrt[2], 
    e + ef < 0 && -4 j + 3 Sqrt[2] Abs[e + ef] > 0 && ef < 0]}}
```

I believe that the first solution you obtained is not relevant, and the Mathematica program made some assumptions you are not aware of.

Hope that helps